# How to iterate over all but first element of an enumerable

Tags: ruby

I run the following code:

```
> a = [1,2,3].collect
 => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:collect> 
> b = a.next
 => 1 
> a.each do |x| puts x end
1
2
3
=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

I would expect the result of the `do` to be `2, 3` since I've already read the first element of `a`.  How I achieve a result of `2, 3` elegantly?

**Edit:**

To clarify, I don't want to skip the first entry, I just want to process it differently.  So I want both `b` and the loop.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

How about this?

```
[1,2,3].drop(1).each {|x| puts x }
# >> 2
# >> 3
```

Here's how you can continue walking the iterator

```
a = [1,2,3]

b = a.each # => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
b.next # skip first one

loop do
  c = b.next
  puts c
end
# >> 2
# >> 3
```

Comment: @Anand: and I also have example output :)

Comment: Thanks, that does it.  Surprised there isn't a built-in way to do this, seems like a common thing to want to do.

Comment: @Stefan: there is a built-in way: `drop(n)` :)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: Question updated to be clearer.  I do want the first value, I'm surprised there isn't a built in way to extract the first value and then continue iteration over the remainder.

Comment: No need to rescue `StopIteration` explicitly, `loop` already does that for you

Answer (score 7):

You could do

```
a.drop(1).each do |x| puts x end
```

EDIT:

Use the `map` method

```
b = [1,2,3].drop(1).map{|x| x}
=> b will be [2, 3]
```

Comment: This works, is there anything more elegant, e.g. something which doesn't require me to replicate the removal of the first element?

Comment: @Stefan Yes i have given one answer as per you.Check if it mets your need or not.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a.shift    
a.each do |x| puts x end
```

Comment: This mutates the original array

Answer (score 3):

As a sidenote, if you're trying to map over all but the first element of an array, array.drop(1).map {} obviously won't work. Instead, you can do something like:

```
[1,2,3].instance_eval { |a| [a.first] + a.drop(1).map { |e| e + 1 } }
```

Comment: Ruby developers are so much more passionate than .NET developers

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
a=[1,2,3]
a.drop(1)
```